# Why do my DOM elements duplicate when I create them?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web based jeopardy game and I seem to have run into an issue.

when I right click to edit a player name a input menu will show up. 
 The next time I click edit two menus pop up... This is kinda hard for me to explain so I linked a video with a demo of what the issue is.

**Javascript Code**

```
let player1_name_edit = document.getElementById('player1-name-edit')
let editButton = document.getElementById('edit-context-menu') // Gets 'edit-context-menu' from DOM 
let inputMenu = document.getElementById('input-menu')
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel-context-menu') // Gets 'cancel-context-menu' from DOM

player1_name_edit.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
    if(event.target == player1_name_edit) {
        event.preventDefault()
        showEditMenu()
        editButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            createInputMenu()
            inputMenu.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
                if(event.key === 'Enter') {
                    let inputMenuValue = document.getElementById('name-input')
                    player1_name_edit.innerText = inputMenuValue.value
                    removeInputMenu()
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

[Video showing error (sorry for the low quality)](https://youtu.be/jRBaXVrEyF8)

Comment: Are you sure `removeInputMenu()` work?

Comment: Every time you right click, you add an event listener to the edit button

Comment: Please click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]. You likely just need to delegate

Comment: Don't nest callback functions this deeply - you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Never add an event listener from an other event listener.

Comment: You're using `addEventListener`, but never [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)